# Исключение при преобразовании string в int

Tags: java

```
String UNP;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

UNP = in.next();

    if(Integer.parseInt(UNP) > 1 && Integer.parseInt(UNP) <= 21)
        out.println("\n      Объект выбран\n");
    else 
        out.println("\n      Ошибка выбора объекта\n");
```

При вводе строки состоящей не только из цифр происходит ошибка.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "qq"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   Levchenko.App.CLIENT_OBJECT.INPUT_UNP(CLIENT_OBJECT.java:44)  at
>   Levchenko.App.Main.main(Main.java:8)
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 2.986s Finished at: Fri Mar 03 22:58:41 MSK 2017 Final
>   Memory: 6M/106M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project App: Command execution failed. Process exited
>   with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Как мне перед преобразованием `string` в `int` и проверкой на соответствие диапазону чисел проверить возможность преобразования `string` в `int` для сравнения?

```
do {

    UNP = in.next();

    if(UNP.matches("\\d+")){
        if(Integer.parseInt(UNP) > 1 && Integer.parseInt(UNP) <= 21)
            out.println("      Объект выбран\n");
        else 
            out.println("      Ошибка выбора объекта\n");
   }
   else
       out.println("      Ошибка выбора объекта\n");
   }    
        while(Integer.parseInt(UNP) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(UNP) > 21);
```

Если введена строка не только с цифрами то условие отрабатывает 1 раз, выводит такую же ошибку и выходит из do while.

Исправил присвоением перед проверкой while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать обработку исключений:

```
String UNP;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

UNP = in.next();
try{
    if(Integer.parseInt(UNP) > 1 && Integer.parseInt(UNP) <= 21)
        System.out.println("\n      Объект выбран\n");
    else 
        System.out.println("\n      Ошибка выбора объекта\n");
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("\n      Неверный формат\n");
}
```

Можно добавить функцию, действие которой также заключается в обработке исключений. Получится примерно так:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    String UNP;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    UNP = in.next();
    if(isNumber(UNP)){
        if(Integer.parseInt(UNP) > 1 && Integer.parseInt(UNP) <= 21)
            System.out.println("\n      Объект выбран\n");
        else 
            System.out.println("\n      Ошибка выбора объекта\n");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("\n      Неверный формат\n");    
}

public static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ещё проверить, является ли строка целым (неотрицательным) числом можно с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
if(UNP.matches("\\d+")){
    if(Integer.parseInt(UNP) > 1 && Integer.parseInt(UNP) <= 21)
        System.out.println("\n      Объект выбран\n");
    else 
        System.out.println("\n      Ошибка выбора объекта\n");
    }
else
    System.out.println("\n      Неверный формат\n");
```

Для любых целых чисел выражение будет такое:

```
UNP.matches("-?\\d+")
```

Comment: А оператором if можно проверить? В одну строку.

Comment: Можно, добавил в ответ. Обрабатывать исключениями намного проще, чем искать иные пути проверки строки, например, регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Возможно без функции? В одну строку.

Comment: Добавил способ с регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Появилась проблема, посмотрите отредактированный вопрос.

Comment: Заведите boolean переменную и проверяйте выход из цикла по ней. https://ideone.com/uhz0vk

Comment: _digit_ - это _цифра_, _number_ - это _число_. Соответственно, метод должен называться `isNumber`.

Comment: Спасибо, подправил.